# WP - troubles with joining two tables

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, join

i was trying to find at the internet the answer, and I found something, but i do not get it :-)

I have just a two tables - wp_users & wp_usermeta. These two tables has the same ID (wp_users.ID and wp_usermeta.user_id). All I want is to take email address from wp_users and join it with nickname from wp_usermeta.

I am beginner in sql and this would be very helpful, if somebody would explain :-) Thank you so much :-)

```
    <?php
    //I just want tu print in echo all user emails connected with their nicknames from two separate tables - wp_users
    //and wp_user_meta. I am trying to connect these tables with "ID" which has these two tables the same (inner join part)
    $teacher_table = "SELECT wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.nickname
                    FROM wp_users,wp_usermeta
                    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id";
    $results_table_main = $wpdb->get_results($teacher_table);

    foreach ($teacher_table as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are trying to join wp_usermeta twice, once with the inner join expression and once by using a comma in the from expression.

Comment: Also you are trying to run the `foreach` loop on a string, it should be `foreach($results_table_main as $value)`

Comment: Now I am getting no error, but also echo will print nothing :-) urghhh, this one is hard one :D

Comment: give me a minute I am writing you up a complete answer :)

Comment: I think the problem will be with manipulating wp_usermeta. In wp_users the column is called "user_email" so that is pretty clear. But I want from user_meta -> meta_key.nickname = and this nickname has to be taken from meta_value column" :-) That is why is this so complicated :-(

Comment: Indeed, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers and comments will help with the issue but the primary problem here is that you are querying a column that does not exist, `wp_usermeta.nickname`

This is what you need to do:

```
$teacher_table = "SELECT wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname'";
```

And just for good measure the rest of your code, note that the returned variable is an object so must be accessed as such.

```
 $results_table_main = $wpdb->get_results($teacher_table);

foreach ($results_table_main as $value){
   echo $value->user_email;
   echo $value->meta_value;
}
```

Comment: plus one for that foreach ;)

Comment: Yeah - logicaly this is way to go :-) Anyway, still getting error -> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in..." Ill try to debug it :-) Thank you anyway :-)

Comment: @WheatBeak , please check the tags after the Question , then please provide the answer ...This Question is related to the Wordpress

Comment: @vjytiwari  Yes I gathered that much from `$wpdb`, and `wp_users`, and `wp_usermeta`....  What's the issue?

Comment: @WheatBeak , still will give the error because you did not declare $wpdb as a global ?

Comment: THIS WORKS! Woooow! And it is also super readable :-) I can finish whole code and I can put it in table :-) You are the best :-) Totaly helped!

Comment: You are my hero for today :-) Answer accepted! Best, I am so freaking happy, I was so frustrated by those weird shortcut solutions on other topics. This is so perfectly readable and reusable :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong query as you required .

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT u.user_email , 
       um.meta_value AS nickname
   FROM wp_users u
   INNER JOIN wp_usermeta um ON u.ID = um.user_id
   WHERE um.meta_key = 'nickname'";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($results as $value){
    echo "EMAIL : ".$value->user_email . "<br/>";
    echo "NICKNAME : ".$value->nickname. "<br/>";
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

I think it will be helpfull

Comment: I am sorry, could you explain, why did you put letter "u" instead of wp_users? And instead of "wp_usermeta" you put "um". This is super confusing for me :-(

Comment: it is easy to write code for me that's why i used alias

Comment: It's just an alias, you can use any word or letter you want after the table and then you don't need to continue writing the entire table name out in the rest of the query.  You can learn more about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)